# Manual Installation Help

Tags: dual-boot, mountpoint

When I install Ubuntu by using something else and create the partitions

What should I usually do is select the mount point as root ie /

I wonder what are the other mount options used for and what can is the best option for booting along with the windows 8 and windows 7

Comment: Just visit the link [Scott](https://askubuntu.com/users/133628/scott-goodgame) has given, it has good explanation for a newbie, just read that article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The something else allows you to mount things like /home to other drives/partitions. I use it all the time to create a seperate /home partition so if I decide to change distros, I can keep all the stuff I have there.
[Help With Partitions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35676/how-to-choose-a-partition-scheme-for-your-linux-pc/)

Comment: I didn't get what you have said can you just say me a bit clear (I am a newbie) or suggest me some links which might be useful :)